# What is the rank of the quadrupole moment tensor in QM and nuclear physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, multipole-expansion

For an assignment on Quantum Mechanics, we have been given an expression for the quadrupole moment of the deuteron

$$\langle Q\rangle = \langle(2z^2-x^2-y^2)\rangle$$

It is known that the quadrupole moment is a rank 2 tensor, but how come it appears to be a scalar from this definition? Is it actually not the quadrupole moment, and just something very similar to it (maybe a projection of the quadrupole moment) commonly referred to as quadrupole moment in nuclear physics?

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how do you get the bra-ket notation in MathJax, I had to copy and paste the text from yours, and I couldn't figure out how to get the characters from online elsewhere.

Comment: Actually I had no clue how to do it, and my post was edited. You can check the edit for this information. @MC2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the notation; what you have written above it the expectation value of the operator, i.e. $$⟨\psi|Q|\psi⟩ = ⟨Q⟩ $$ is clearly a scalar, but we can see from the operation of Q that it is a rank 2 tensor.

It is perhaps worth adding that a rank(a,b) tensor can be defined as an operator that takes in a covariant vectors and b contravariant vectors, and returns a scalar, in addition to the multi-linearity properties. So in this case, $Q$ is a rank(1,1) tensor, and hence takes in a total of 2 vectors, (the bra and ket) and returns a scalar.

Comment: Is this so? The expected value of vector operators are vectors, and of scalar operators, scalars. Wouldn't it be reasonable that the expected value of a rank 2 operator be a rank 2 tensor as well?

Comment: A vector operator is really just 3 (or however many it ends up being) scalar operators in one equation.

Comment: But here we get no 9 scalar results, we only get one.

Comment: Why would you expect 9 scalar results?

Comment: Because if vector operators are 3 scalar operators, one would expect a rank 2 tensor to be 9 scalar operators.

Comment: See my edited answer, I think you are misunderstanding either bra-ket notation, or tensors and linear operators in general, or both. It may be worthwhile simply going over the first few chapters of a QM book again as a refresher. Also each component of a vector operator in QM is typically a rank 2 tensor.

Comment: Oh, I didn't ever think of it as a rank(1,1) tensor, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you, accepting.